# How to use "There's no choice ..."

Tags: word-choice

Is this sentence correct?

> There was no choice for me to go to school while I really wanted to visit my friend at the hospital yesterday morning

I’m most concerned with how to correctly use “There’s no choice” in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a "but":

> There was no choice **but** for me to go to school yesterday.  I would rather have visited my friend at the hospital.

You can also say "I had no choice but ..."

> **I had no choice but** to go to school yesterday, instead of visiting my friend at the hospital like I wanted.

Side note:  British speakers frequently say "at hospital" instead of "at **the** hospital".